# How can I attach handlers for each group of childs?

Tags: jquery, handler

Suppose I have this html scenario :

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
</div>          

<div class="parent">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
</div>
```

well, on `child` link I'd like to count the size of that group. But if I click on a link from the first group, it must be 3, not 4.

So I need to attach an handler for each group. Tried :

```
$('.parent .child').size();
```

but the count is always 4. How can I do it?

Also, notice that for a single link, without parents :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
```

it must works as well.(size is 1, also if it is not inside any "parent" group)

Best way on doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very elegant, but it should get the job done.

```
$('a.child').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('a.child').first().addClass('first');
});
$('a.child.first').parent().each(function() {
    alert($(this).children('a.child').size());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XFbWn/4/

Note, you'll get 1-3-1 instead of 3-1-1.. I'm assuming this is because the `a.child` with no parent gets grabbed by the selector first, since it's higher in the DOM tree than the others `a.child`'s

**EDIT**: The above is a solution to the answer as written. Below is an updated version for the use case the author describes in the comments

http://jsfiddle.net/XFbWn/8/

```
$('a.child').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('a.child').first().addClass('first');
});
var i = 0;
$('a.child.first').removeClass('first').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('a.child').addClass('colorBoxGroup-' + i);
    $('.colorBoxGroup-' + i).colorbox({ rel: 'colorBoxGroup-' + i, transition: "fade", maxWidth: "900px", maxHeight: "600px" });
    i++;
});
```

​

Comment: That's how I read the question too. One thing - if it's only direct child elements he wants, he may at some point add more things into the div and that could spoil it if he used the child class again.  You could use `children("a.child")` to find the direct children only.

Comment: That should fix the extra scenario that he threw in as well ;)

Comment: `Object [object Object] has no method 'child'` :O

Comment: It seems to works! (with size). Unfortunatly if I use .lightBox, the count is different! Damn...

Comment: what is .lightBox? You can use any class you want in place of `child`

Comment: @markzzz If you have another question then you should ask it as another question.  Don't expand on an already asked and answered one.

Comment: It is related! In fact my original question was on "attach an handler" on these elements. Not on "click". In that case, I should "browse" every elements, and attach the right handler. In this case, I should see the alert "3-1-1". How can I should do it?

Comment: I can't do an `each` on a.child :)

Comment: Do you understand what I mean? :)

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm thinking haha. This would be significantly easier if every `a.child` had a consistent parent ;)

Comment: Since the parents aren't known, you'll have to do `each`, and then filter them in some fashion

Comment: That's difficult! Honestly, I don't know how to do...! The only think is, on click, destroy handler and put a new one! But won't be so performant... that's why it will be better handle them on load...

Comment: on click? You're changing your question again >_<. Your result is going to be difficult because your question is intrinsically difficult... You want to know how many `a.child`'s there are in a "group", when a "group" can be any element in the DOM.. And then attach handlers to this "group". This isn't a one- or two-liner ;)

Comment: Which elements are getting a click handler? The `a.child`'s or the "group"'s? We don't have to do all that traversing every time -- Just once. That's just what we need to do to find out what our "group" elements are.

Comment: Click was an example, as you post as .click!

Comment: Uhm, seems works! Nice solution, why "not so elegant"? :) In any case, this won't work with "handlers", because I need to attack it on every element inside the group, not only the ".first" one. Example with handler : http://jsfiddle.net/XFbWn/5/

Comment: (in fact it works only on the last element, which is, for the DOM, the "first")

Comment: @markzzz The colorbox-specific solution is a bit different than what your question suggests. Don't be afraid to include context in your questions! Over-generalizing your question can lead people in the wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="parent" id='group1'>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
</div>          

<div class="parent">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="child">Link</a>
</div>
$('#group1 .child').size();
```

Comment: Well, of course it works. I need to do a things for every elements, not by ID :)